# Dynamically add usercontrol to tab panel at center

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am adding usercontrol to the tab panel dynamically how do i add it to the center location 
with respect to tab panel?

Comment: The answer: depends on the used UI framework. Winforms behaves completely different from Silverlight, and both differ greatly from Mono (I think; I haven't used Mono yet).

Answer (score 2):

The *Location* and *Anchor* properties of the control should allow you to position the control dynamically.

```
        this.userControl.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
                    | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                    | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.userControl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(108, 85);
```